# Angular 5 images not loading from assets directory

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to load images from the assets directory but they do not load in the view. This is what's happening;

1. In assets directory I have a bunch of sub folders with images in the subfolders (icons and flags for instance)

`assets_
        |-img_
              |-icons_
                      |-copyright.png
              |-flags_
                      |-ch.png
                      |-us.png`

2. In the view I have the image paths as

`<img src="assets/img/flags/jp.png" alt="">` and `<img src="assets/img/icons/copyright.png" alt="">`

3. The Errors.

[image: image doesn't load in the view]

The image doesn't load in the view yet for a weird reason, the image in icons dir loads just fine.

When I inspect, this is what I discovered the following network call which is looking for the image from the root instead of `assets`.

[image]

[image]

Second, it says type is `text/html` instead of `png` and the initiator as `VM639:330`?!

However when I scroll further up, I discover the image had earlier been loaded just fine and the type and initiator are perfectly fine (`png` and `index`).

[image]

What exactly is going wrong here? Why can't I load images from the assets directory?

Comment: So for every image in your asset folder it's working fine except for the `flags`? Can you double-check that there's not reference to the flags other than `assets/img/`, so not starting with a `/`?
A comment on the "type": Because there is no file at `/img/flags/jp.png` the angular-cli dev server responds with the homepage by default. This is a `text/html` file, so this is ok.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the solution - I searched the entire project to discover a js script was responsible for resetting the paths. You could answer the question so I can select it as the answer

Comment: Not sure whether that's actually a "problem" for Stackoverflow then, as the problem only occurred because of a typo...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, image or icon in assets/image can not be displayed (404 not found).
To resolve this I defined a variables like this in my component.ts

```
img = require('../../../../assets/images/excel.png')
```

the number of point depends on template place in the source folder.
 in the template I opt for this

```
 <img  [src]="img"/>
```

Note: This is not the best solution, i am looking for one better.